# learn how hosting companies setup accounts on servers

Tags: unix

Are there any HOTWO's or books that go over real world, best practices, on setting up a computer like unix hosting companies do?

Comment: Yes. There are many.

Answer (score 2):

That is a loaded question if I ever saw one.

But, in a nutshell, most just install a web hosting control panel like cPanel, and call it a day. And I am sure it has "best practices" chapter where they recommend the best settings for the server. I could be wrong on the second part, though, but it only makes sense.

Some other control panels:

- zPanel
- Plesk

Of course VPS systems:

- VMWare Server
- Microsoft Virtual Server

I'll let my peers fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 1):

Practices vary between hosting companies.  No two I've worked for do it even vaguely the same.  Your best bet is to find someone who works at a hosting company and buy them beers.

Answer (score 1):

They all have their own, but for a quick down and dirty i would suggest you look at http://www.howtoforge.com/instaling_ehcp_on_debian_ubuntu . there are several other ones on that site as well